# Eliminar corchetes de un arraylist para pasarl elementos como parametros de un procedimiento almacenado Java

Tags: java, array, oracle, funciones, jdbc

Buenas noches tengo un problema y necesito ayuda.
mi problema es que quiero ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado, pero los parámetros de dicho procedimiento almacenado los tengo en un arraylist. y como sabrán el arraylist imprime el resultado con corchetes.

```
List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < respuestavo.size(); i++) {
//Guardo los valores en la lista res.
            res.add(respuestavo.get(i).getRespuestas());
        }
```

pero al ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado se ejecuta con la siguiente sintaxis necesito eliminar los corchetes.

```
CALL UTIC.UZTKPROCESOS.P_GENERA_ARCHIVO_PAGOS(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?),[201950, CE, 07/10/2020, 07/10/2020, 334571, 7, 2]
```

Utilicé la función replace, pero no me conviene porque replace me hace convertir mi lista en un string.

```
    String parametros = res.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    resultado del replace: 201950, CE, 07/10/2020, 07/10/2020, 334571, 7, 2
```

pero al ejecutar el procedimiento no reconoce los parámetros xq es una cadena de texto, aunque la sintaxis está correcta, cada parametro debe estar separado x una coma.

```
CALL UTIC.UZTKPROCESOS.P_GENERA_ARCHIVO_PAGOS(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?),201950, CE, 07/10/2020, 07/10/2020, 334571, 7, 2
```

hay alguna forma de quitar los corchetes de la lista sin tener que convertirla a string o alguna otra opcion para pasar la lista como parametros.

ejecucion del procedimiento con repalce, lista convertida en string;

```
jdbcTemplate.update("CALL UTIC.UZTKPROCESOS.P_GENERA_ARCHIVO_PAGOS(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" , parametros);
```

ejecucion del procedimiento directamente desde la lista

```
jdbcTemplate.update("CALL UTIC.UZTKPROCESOS.P_GENERA_ARCHIVO_PAGOS(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" , res);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La declaración del método update es:

```
public int update(String sql,
                      @Nullable
                      Object... args)
```

Como se puede ver, el segundo argumento es un arreglo `Object... args`.

Se puede convertir la lista a un arreglo con el método `toArray()`.

```
jdbcTemplate.update("query" , res.toArray());
```

Comment: muchas gracias, resolviste mi problema